# How do I interact the rasa assistant from the command line?

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

When creating a new rasa assistant with `rasa init` I get the interface below. What command can I run from the command line to get back to this interface after I exit? Sometimes I'd rather just use the cmd interface rather than running `rasa x` and using the browser.

```
? Do you want to speak to the trained assistant on the command line?   Yes
2020-11-03 10:01:30 INFO     root  - Connecting to channel 'cmdline' which was specified by the '--connector' argument. Any other channels will be ignored. To connect to all given channels, omit the '--connector' argument.
2020-11-03 10:01:30 INFO     root  - Starting Rasa server on http://localhost:5005
2020-11-03 10:01:32 INFO     root  - Rasa server is up and running.
Bot loaded. Type a message and press enter (use '/stop' to exit):
Your input ->  hi
Hey! How are you?
Your input ->  good
Great, carry on!
Your input ->  I am sad
Great, carry on!
Your input ->  hi
Hey! How are you?
Your input ->  bad
Here is something to cheer you up:
Image: https://i.imgur.com/nGF1K8f.jpg
Did that help you?
Your input ->  /stop
2020-11-03 10:02:38 INFO     root  - Killing Sanic server now.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after running `rasa init`, now you have your project ready, and model has been trained. To get this interface back, in command Line interface your have to run `rasa shell` which will load trained model and lets you talk to your assistant on the command line.

Comment: `rasa shell` gives you the intent and confidence information; I don't want any of that, I simply want to interact with the assistant and get responses back. I may be asking for something that is not available in Rasa. Just seems like you should be able to do it since you can do it when you first initialize it.

Answer (score 1):

Also for posterity, I wanted to add this an answer. I had been doing `rasa train nlu` prior to running `rasa shell` which was creating an NLU only model.

To be able to converse with the assistant at the command line I need to first run `rasa train` then run `rasa shell`.